# Howto to execute onclick of each tag table (tr) with Webdriver Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, navigation, back

I have a html table with onclick on the tr tag. This "click" send me to a new web page, and then I need to go back to previous page and continue to the next "tr click". 
[image]

Until now, I achieve to execute the first onclick, then when I go back, Selenium give me this error.

> stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

The code I have

```
            IWebElement table = driver.FindElement(By.Name("pg_table"));
            IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> rows = table.FindElements(By.XPath(".//tr[@onclick]"));
            IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
            int rowCurrent = 0;
            foreach (IWebElement row in rows)
            {

                js.ExecuteScript($"arguments[{rowCurrent}].click();", row);
                var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
                wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("/html/body")));

                //retreive data from the new page....

                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                driver.Navigate().Back();
                ++rowCurrent;
           }
```

Can you help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this with this,  first I get all the onclick javascript in a list

```
List<string> linksPbds = new List<string>();

IWebElement table = driver.FindElement(By.Name("pg_table"));
IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> rows = table.FindElements(By.XPath(".//tr[@onclick]"));

foreach (IWebElement row in rows)
{
  linksPbds.Add(row.GetAttribute("onclick"));
}
```

then I iterate each member of the list and execute the javascript

```
foreach (var link in links)
{
    js.ExecuteScript(link);
    var airlineCode = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/form/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]")).Text;
    .... other html element
}
```

I don´t know if ths is best approach , but this work for me.